# Using ctype.h with utf-8 character

Tags: c, utf-8, ascii, ctype

I'm study C from Kernighan and Ritchie (1988), which use ASCII in character manipulation. In chapter 2, they start using the header file *ctype.h*. Searching in internet and reading the comments in *ctype.h* file, they wrote that is for ascii; so it makes sense that for other encoding of characters as utf-8 don't work so well.

I was printing the value of `iscnctr()` for the values between `0`-`32` and `127`-`159` (decimal); and I was expecting that it would return `0` or `1`, but instead, it return `0` and `32`.

Why it doesn't return `0` or `1`? And there is *ctype.h* for utf-8?

Comment: "iscnctr"? you mean `iscntrl`?

Comment: "I'm study C from Kernighan and Ritchie (1988)" - that's a mistake by the way. Similar to studying astronomy by reading the works of Ptolemy on geocentrism. Today's C language is *related* to the original K&R but has advanced a long way since then.

Comment: It's not hard to write a ctype-like library for utf-8 strings. I did one a while ago. Converting to wchar is not necessary. Note that the isX functions are usually done as a table lookup for speed. In your library bit 5 indicates it is a control char. Other bits are upper, lower, digit, etc.

Comment: @paxdiablo Do you recommend another book?

Comment: @stark I did something like that because I felt necessary before reading about *ctype.h*, but I don't know if is "efficient" because just check for dec value in a utf-8 table

Comment: See [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/15168).  I'd recommend  N King
[C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edn](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0393979504/) 2008.  There are other decent modern books in the list.  There are many books to avoid too, but most of them are not listed in the SO Q&A.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, I'd check them, and what do you mean by SO Q&A?

Comment: SO = Stack Overflow; Q&A = Question and Answer(s).  The "definitive list" has the form of a question and answer on Stack Overflow, as opposed to being a Q&A on some other site.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it doesn't return 0 or 1?

The `is*` functions from `ctype.h` return zero if the character does not meet the condition and **non-zero** otherwise. Any non-zero. `32` is non-zero.

Looking at [cppreference isctrl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/iscntrl) it should return non-zero for 0-31 and 127 for ASCII.

> there is ctype.h for utf-8?

The short answer is no. UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding. Function from `ctype.h` are for single byte narrow characters.

The *standard way*, is when you have a string containing a multibyte character (in the [C programming sense](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte)) first convert it to wide characters by *first setting the appropriate locale for your environment* and then call the `mbtowc`. Then you can use `isw*` function from `wctype.h` to identify the character category.

> Why is 32 tho?

Because of a tiny amount of speed, that was relevant 50 years ago. Changing bitwise result to 0/1 is an additional operation. Nowadays, it doesn't make a difference, which is why modern programming languages have bool. 50 years ago, there was no bool in C and single operations were much more important.

It is usually implemented like the following. [There is a big table that maps of every character to a single byte with flags](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/2a63fa0fd26ffb6603f69d9e369e944fe449c246/newlib/libc/ctype/ctype_.c#L40).

```
char map[256] = { 0, 0, _ISCTRL_FLAG | _ISUPPER_FLAG, ..... etc for 256 bytes .... };
```

Then all `isctrl` is [checks bitwise if a bit inside a map is set](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/include/ctype.h#L59).

```
enum {
  _ISCTRL_FLAG = 32;
};
static inline
int isctrl(unsigned char c) {
   returm map[c] & _ISCTRL_FLAG;
}
```

Because the result of `&` is equal to `_ISCTRL_FLAG` when the bit is set, the result is 32 or 0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that condicional statement check for non-zero as true value, but that "32" I find it weird. Why is 32 tho?

Comment: Possibly it's doing bit testing that finishes with AND 32, since control characters don't have the 32-bit set (although some non-control chars also don't have it set)... a byte AND 32 will be 0 if the bit is not set, and 32 if it is set.

Comment: On the thing about converting to wide, if `wchar_t` stores a variable-length encoding (such as UTF-16LE on Windows), aren't the `isw*` functions still not feasible in the case where a code point is encoded as multiple `wchar_t`s?

Comment: `if wchar_t stores a variable-length encoding (such as UTF-16LE on Windows)` yes, it means windows does not handle all unicode code points with wide characters, because they rushed for utf-16 and couldn't change for utf-32. So now on windows, which I know nothing about, they use ICU library most probably. `where a code point is encoded as multiple wchar_ts?` The standard wide characters is a single byte encoding. It is just not supported. I do not know what happens on windows when you try to convert from utf-8 to wide character for higher codepoints.

Answer (score 1):

In C, *any* nonzero value is considered true, so many Boolean functions return whatever is easiest to return rather than arranging to return 1. So if you expect a Boolean result, just use it in a Boolean context; don't chck for equality to 1.

However, you can coerce it to 0 or 1 by negating it twice with `!!`.

As far as Unicode, C doesn't really support it. It has regular one-byte `char`s and multibyte `wchar_t`s, but the latter aren't required to be UTF-8 or any specific encoding. You can find libraries that will check properties against UniData, but there aren't any `ctyep`-like functions for Unicode in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would search for a ctype lib for unicode por maybe do it when I learned more.